# Alphabetically sorting a multidimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter

take this multidimensional `array` for example:

`$array = array(
     '0' => array("name"=>"xyc",...),
     '1' => array("name"=>"abc",...)
 );`

Is there a way I can sort this array alphabetically with respect to the 'name' index in it's second dimension?

I have looked in the php manual and I have tried the `asort` function but it didn't work.

*please don't get confused with the continuation dots I have given in the array.*

Comment: Check this [PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: Here is a function that might help [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `usort` for this :

```
/*just example here*/  
<?php
$arr = array(
    0 => array('name' => 'xyc'),
    1 => array('name' => 'abc'),
    2 => array('name' => 'mno')
);

function test($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}
usort($arr, 'test');

print_r($arr);
```

See the demo : https://eval.in/999990

see more : ;http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php